# How do you set a DateTimePicker to be read only?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

I have a DateTimePicker (nullable version) that I need to be read only.  I'm not happy with the display if it is disabled, so wanted to know if anyone had a nifty example of how to stop updates on the field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could hook the Changed event, and set the value back to your desired value (if different) -- this way you'll cover any cause for change (via mouse, or keyboard)

Have you considered using a different control, such as a read only textbox or even a label control?

Comment: This results in a box that appears to be editable but the value changes back to the old value when you leave the date picker.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is very old but to help anyone else searching for this (As it was the first one I found through google) You can use:

```
this.dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
```

to make it act the same way as a a textbox would with `this.textbox1.ReadOnly = true`

Comment: Simple solution that I totally overlooked (as usual). Worked for my case. The only way this solution wouldn't be all that desirable, is if you didn't like the greyed out look which you don't get with `ReadOnly = true`.

Comment: Enabled is not the same as read only.  When a text box is read only you can still click into it, move the caret around, select the text and copy it.

Answer (score 3):

This question--after six years--still seems to get some interest so I'll throw in my 2 cents: What works for me is 1) Make a UserControl and change the base class to DateTimePicker 2) Take a little bitmap snapshot of the control whenever the value changes 3) Intercept the WM_PAINT message and if our control is disabled draw the bitmap instead of the control.
(Note: AutoScaleMode property in designer.cs makes compile error so just remove)

```
public partial class DateTimePickerWithReadOnly : DateTimePicker
{
  Bitmap ReadOnlyImage;
  // We maintain a "shadow" control to avoid capturing selections in the snapshot.
  // If you use different formatting or styles just make sure the shadow is set to match!
  DateTimePicker Shadow = new DateTimePicker(); 
  public DateTimePickerWithReadOnly()
  {
    InitializeComponent(); 
    CaptureBitmap();
    this.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(DateTimePickerWithReadOnly_ValueChanged);
  }
  private void CaptureBitmap()
  {
    Shadow.Value = Value;
    Shadow.Size = Size;
    ReadOnlyImage = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    Shadow.DrawToBitmap(ReadOnlyImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height));
  }
  void DateTimePickerWithReadOnly_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    CaptureBitmap();
  }
  protected override void DefWndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    base.DefWndProc(ref m);
    // WM_PAINT is 0x000F
    if ((m.Msg == 0x000F) && !Enabled)
    {
      Graphics g = base.CreateGraphics();
      g.DrawImage(ReadOnlyImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height));
      g.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way I've done this is to simply constrain the allowable range of dates to a single value.

```
dateTimePicker.MinDate = dateTimePicker.Value;
dateTimePicker.MaxDate = dateTimePicker.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

As another suggestion:  Use a textbox (or a label) and make it read only.  Display the value you want in it.

If you have to have a datetimepicker, create both a datetimepicker and a textbox.  Lay them on top of each other.  When you need the datetimepicker, hid the textbox.  Etc.

Answer (score 2):

on Keydown:  e.SuppressKeyPress = true; worked for me, can still pick a date, but can't enter manually

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm not happy with the display if it is disabled"

Why? If it's because a disabled text box looks weird, you can just change the disabled style to make it look normal, or indicate in a prettier way that it accepts input only through the date picker. Possibly have no borders on it, to say it's not really a text box.

Comment: Can you point me which property is that, please? I thought I can't change the disabled style in winforms, but if it's possible, I would like to. Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry... it's been over four years now and I can't remember a thing about this answer or what I was talking about :(

Answer (score 1):

I know it's years out of date but i hate finding problems that are still relevant with no solution. By the way, the reason you might not want to have it disabled is that you cannot easily display tooltips and custom backcolour (although this can be more easily worked around)

Anyway, I found the solution to this (thanks to others on here elsewhere) that i believe the question asks. I already had a custom control for DateTimePicker.

I then added a Readonly property. My problem was in a VB.Net proj

Override the KeyDown event and mark as handled if Readonly = True.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
  If mReadOnly Then
    e.Handled = True
  Else
    MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
  End If
End Sub
```

This takes care of the arrow keys and the F4 drop down key.

Then to disable the dropdown, override the WndProc method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
  '   m.Msg = 0x201 / &H201 = WM_LBUTTONDOWN
  '   m.Msg = 0x203 / &H203 = WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
  If ReadOnly And (m.Msg = &H201 Or m.Msg = &H203) Then
    Return
  End If
  MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub
```

To make it look Readonly in my OnPaint override, i have the following:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()

Dim dropDownIcon As Rectangle = New Rectangle(ClientRectangle.Width - 17, 0, 17, ClientRectangle.Height)
Dim b As Brush
Dim v As VisualStyles.ComboBoxState
Dim vn As ButtonState

b = New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)

If Me.IsReadOnly Then
  v = VisualStyles.ComboBoxState.Disabled
  vn = ButtonState.Inactive
Else
  b = New SolidBrush(Me.BackColor)
    v = VisualStyles.ComboBoxState.Normal
    vn = ButtonState.Normal
  End If

'changed to only do this if the control is visible
If Me.Visible = True Then

  'colour rectangle
  g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height)

  'for border 
  g.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.SystemPens.ActiveBorder, 0, 0, ClientRectangle.Width - 1, ClientRectangle.Height - 1)

  'for text
  g.DrawString(Me.Text, Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor), 0, 2)


  'we need to render the dropdown when visual styles is not turned on
  If ComboBoxRenderer.IsSupported Then
    ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(g, dropDownIcon, v)
  Else
    ControlPaint.DrawComboButton(g, dropDownIcon, vn)
  End If
End If

g.Dispose()
b.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

handle the DateTimePicker.MouseClick Event and set the event.handled to true

Comment: You'd also need to disable keyboard input that would change the value

Answer (score 0):

How about just picking up the Changed event and setting e.Cancel = true?

Comment: This would not work. The event is Chang**ed**. As in the value has already been modified. You cannot simply cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Not the nicest way to do it but this does stop the update of datetime by keyUp

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private DateTime originalValue;

    private void dateTimePicker1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        originalValue = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = originalValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. We have to remember original datetime firstly.

   ```
   procedure TForm1.dtpDateEnter(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     oldDtpDate := dtpDate.DateTime;
   end;
   ```
2. procedure TForm1.dtpDateClick(Sender: TObject);
       begin
         dtpDate.DateTime :=  oldDtpDate;
       end;

   ```
   procedure TForm1.dtpDateExit(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     dtpDate.DateTime :=  oldDtpDate;
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
this.dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
```

It is one of the simple and perfect solutions.

Comment: Enabled is not the same as read only.  When a text box is read only you can still click into it, move the caret around, select the text and copy it.

Answer (score -1):

`dateTimePicker2.Enabled = false;`

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is not the only value you want to be able to use.